# Calculate the difference between Numbers in the same row - different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, difference

Sorry if it has been answered before, I just could not find it. I am trying to calculate the difference between columns in the same row, same calculation as Difference from a specific Value in excel pivot.

What the table says i.e in 1st row is that we had 39 different customers first registering on 2019/01 , then only 5 of them repurchased on 2019/02, only 2 of them in 2019/03 etc.

I want a new table where it shows the difference between 2019/01-2019/02, 2019/01-2019/03 etc. so under 2019/01 shows 0, under 2019/02 shows 34, under 2019/03 shows 37 etc for each row ( basically subtracting from the 1st value of the row)

Is it possible?

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8oxd.png)

[PBI Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j0jz.png)- I can create the first table as it is a simple count, but i cannot create the Loss and Loss Rate tables in PBI

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: i have uploaded an image as a link. is it not working?

Comment: is the image containing your input data? this is how data stored in table? Finally, if it is input data, show what output you wants. Output should based on sample input data with calculation details.

Comment: I have uploaded both the raw data  and how i want them visualized in PBI. is this what you asked for ? thank you for your effort so far .

Comment: Hi @Jojo, I must appreciate your effort for creating sample data and output. But to much data and sample output always make thing difficult to understand. It would be great if your keep minimum sample data and output that covered all scenario. Sorry for to many change request.

Comment: @mkRabbani thank you for the tips, sorry for this I am very new to Stackoverflow so all guidance is appreciated. I have edited both links with the raw data and pbi visual. tell me if this is better. again thanks

Comment: @mkRabbani Sorry for the late reply I had trouble irl with covid. Please see below answer for my problem as it is not working. again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom column to your table as below-

```
column_january = "January"
```

**Now for customer activity**, add a Matrix in the report and configure the Matrix properties as below-

[image]

With some change in properties like - "Grand Total", "Sub Total" and "Per Row Level" you will get this below presentation-

[image]

**Now for customer lost**, Create a measure as below-

```
customer_lost = 

VAR current_year = MIN(your_table_name[activity date].[Year])

VAR customer_starts_with = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(your_table_name[customer]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[activity date].[Year] = current_year
            && your_table_name[activity date].[Month] = "January"
    )
)

RETURN IF(MIN(your_table_name[customer]) = BLANK(),BLANK(),customer_starts_with - MIN(your_table_name[customer]))
```

Now add a Matrix in the report and configure the Matrix properties as below-

[image]

With some change in properties like - "Grand Total", "Sub Total" and "Per Row Level" you will get this below presentation-

[image]

**Your final measure for customer lost** will be as below- (convert the measure type as %). Just copy your matrix for customer lost and replace replace measure "Customer Lost" with "Customer Lost Percentage" in the Values field for your presentation.

```
customer_lost_percentage = 

VAR current_year = MIN(difference[activity date].[Year])

VAR customer_starts_with = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(difference[customer]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(difference),
        difference[activity date].[Year] = current_year
            && difference[activity date].[Month] = "January"
    )
)

VAR customer_lost = IF(MIN(difference[customer]) = BLANK(),BLANK(),customer_starts_with - MIN(difference[customer]))

RETURN customer_lost/customer_starts_with
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i need for the row of January. The other rows should not be populated , as the calculation is based on the FD_date column

Comment: Necessity of having only row for January, makes the requirement more easy. I am updating the whole answer now.

Answer (score 0):

For the matrix to be like you said above i have to use

[image: matrix]

So when i try to replace the customers_lost code to

```
customer_lost = 

VAR current_year = MIN(Month_Retention[FD_Date])

VAR customer_starts_with = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(Month_Retention[Customers]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Month_Retention),
        Month_Retention[FD_Date] = current_year
            && Month_Retention[Activity_Date].[Month] = "January"
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    MIN(Month_Retention[Customers]) = BLANK(),
    BLANK(),
    customer_starts_with - MIN(Month_Retention[Customers])
)
```

it is just not working properly because I believe I made the wrong replacements.

Comment: One difference I found you escaped YEAR conversion in the Code. Do your column Month_Retention[FD_Date] directly holding the YEAR value rather than Date value?

Comment: @mkRabbani my problem is that when i put year it is showing both 2020 and 2019 , because i have data running from 01/01/2019 until today

Comment: can you provide me a sample pbix file with some sample data?

Comment: @mkRabbani https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqkoUE3VUHOOjAoTDpAwvdtvvugW?e=bcEIuJ

Comment: check this updated report- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qBYsEqWSzsVZqyBMY_xE6DbMRHSRBMRZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the 2019 is exactly what i  want to show, but the activity moves to 2020 as well that is where i got confused, with putting the "year" into the activity matrix for rows. I am not sure what the 2020 row with "8" is but i don't think it should be there.  Do you think it will be easier if i exchange rows and columns and subtract from the top row?

Comment: If 2020 is not require,  just filter from the visual.